# Is there way to get the details of client connections

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Is there way to get the details of client connections in Ignite/Gridgain cluster.

1. Number of active connections
2. Number of total connections (active+inactive)
3. Is there any parameter to close the inactive client connections after x seconds?

Comment: @AndreyBelyaev You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1,2 You can use ignite metrics to obtain thin client connections information.
Check out this article https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/new-metrics#ignite-thin-client-connector

3 Probably, idle timeout is exactly what you are looking for
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/ClientConnectorConfiguration.html#setIdleTimeout-long-